# Fabric.js custom build with IText

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, fabricjs

I am trying to make a custom build of Fabric.js with IText.

I use this command:

```
node build.js modules=text,serialization,parser,itext minifier=uglifyjs
```

and this seems to work. I copy the generated `all.min.js` to my project (after renaming it).

But when I try to run this line:

```
self.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasHtml.find('canvas')[0]);
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

If I try typing `fabric.Canvas` in Chrome console it can not find it (`fabric.IText` is there).

So I am wondering how to make a custom build with the modules mentioned above?

It works when building from [this page](http://fabricjs.com/build/) but as far as I can see that does not support iText module.

Comment: You're missing "interaction" module. That's what gives `fabric.Canvas`; otherwise there's just `fabric.StaticCanvas`.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. (I also needed animation module to get IText to work properly)

Comment: I removed the label iText as this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the PDF library iText (iText is a registered trademark owned by 1T3XT)